# How can I get the weather data imported into the MySQL database with my current code?

Tags: java

I know I don't return anything but I don't know how to return the right thing to import the data into the database. In the current code the part where I get the data from openweathermap works fine :D.

```
public class GetTemperature {

   ConnectDatabase connectB; 
   PreparedStatement state;

    public  PreparedStatement getTemp() throws IOException, JSONException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, NullPointerException  {

        try{
            // gets data from openWeatherMap
            ReadUrl read = new ReadUrl();
            JSONObject readEx = read.readUrl();

            //searches true openweathermap for tempData
            double kelvin = 271.15;
            Object temp = readEx.getJSONObject("main").get("temp");
            double tempA = (double) temp - kelvin;

            System.out.println("OWM" + tempA);

            //Database connection with query to import tempData in database
            ConnectDatabase connectB = new ConnectDatabase();
            //Connection connectA = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project3","root","my_password");

            PreparedStatement state = connectB.ConnectDb().prepareStatement("insert into weather (weather_temp)"
            + "values (?)");
            {
                state.setDouble(2,tempA);
            }
            //return state.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("DB" + state.executeUpdate());
            connectB.ConnectDb().close();
            //connectA.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            e.getStackTrace();
            }

        return state;
    }

}
```

**This code worked**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rotterdam,id_key");
double kelvin = 271;
try{
    //public class setAtributes{
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    Time time = new Time(utilDate.getTime());

    Object temp = json.getJSONObject("main").get("temp");
    double tempA = (double) temp - kelvin;

    Object hum = json.getJSONObject("main").get("humidity");
    int humA = (int) hum;

    System.out.println(sqlDate);
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(tempA);
    System.out.println(humA);
   // }

    System.out.println("Test " + i);
  // public class connectDatabase (setAtributes){
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project3","root","my_password");

    PreparedStatement state = connect.prepareStatement("insert into weather ( date, weather_temp, weather_hum, weather_starttime, weather_endtime)"
    + "values (?,?,?,?,?)");

    {
    state.setDate(1,sqlDate);
    state.setDouble(2,tempA);
    state.setInt(3,humA);
    state.setTime(4,time);
    state.setTime(5,time);


   }


    System.out.println(state.executeUpdate());
    //System.out.println(stateR.execute());

    connect.close();


    //wait 10 mins
      Thread.sleep(6000);
    }



catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println("You have an exception");
    System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: i formulated the question wrong. I need to get the data imported into the database ;p. I'm sorry

Comment: Then click on the "edit" link below the question, and formulate it properly. While you're editing, select the code and click on the `{}` button to format it as a code block.

Comment: i hoop this is more clear now.

Comment: In `setDouble()`, the number is supposed to be the number of the question mark in the propared statement. You have only one question mark, so `setDouble(2,...)` doesn't make sense. Also, there is no space between `(weather_temp)` and `values` so it may cause a syntax error.

Comment: ok. I will change it. I made an earlier project where i put the code in the main. At that moment it worked great. How is this differend from that?

Comment: Can't say if you don't show that other project. But I think it would be a waste of time to start comparing projects. Concentrate on correcting your current one.

Comment: Now you can see the working code. But it is a mess that's why i'm splitting it up in classes. The ajusment didnt' make improvement ;p. Thanx :D for the help btw.

Comment: So I guess the space doesn't matter to MySQL (though you should still get the habit of adding space after every `+"` when you build a query, because there are other places in the query where it will most definitely create a syntax error.) But you can see for yourself that you used numbers by the order of the question marks in `setDate()`, `setDouble()` etc., so you should do the same.

Comment: Okay i changed it but it didn't make a difference.